# YII1.1 remember me not working

Tags: php, yii

i have implemented Yii 1.1. everything is working file but remember me is not working.
my code is as below.

1. in config main.php

   ```
   'user' => array(
       // enable cookie-based authentication
       'allowAutoLogin' => true,
   ),
   ```
2. in site controller login action.

   ```
   public function actionLogin() {
       $this->layout = "simple";
       $model = new LoginForm;
       // if it is ajax validation request
       if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form') {
           echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
           Yii::app()->end();
       }

       // collect user input data
       if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
           $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
           // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
           if ($model->validate() && $model->login())
               $this->redirect(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) . "/site/index");
       }
       // display the login form
       $this->render('login', array('model' => $model));
   }
   ```
3. in loginForm model

   ```
   public function login()
   {
       $session=new CHttpSession;
       $session->open();

       if($this->_identity===null)
       {
           $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
           $this->_identity->authenticate();
       }
       if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
       {                  
           $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
           Yii::app()->user->setId($session["uid"]);
           Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
           return true;
       }
       else
           return false;
   }
   ```

I have tried to to check remember me field exists or not so if i have selected then i got remember me value true and also duration set and also applies to that and in the end it returns me true. But Once i logged out and check the login form then not auto-completed username and password?

Comment: That's not how the remember me works. It keeps you logged in (using a cookie instead of a session) when you close the web application. When you logout, that cookie is destroyed even if remember me was ticked. Your browser is what handles auto filling forms and remembering login details, remember me just keeps you logged in for an amount of time even if the browser is closed

Comment: Thanks @eskimo .. so auto complete username and password can we save  from our appllication or it  is totally browser specific?

Comment: Browser specific as far as I know.